# Understanding Security and Secret Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, github, secret-key

I am making a Rails application and am trying to understand security as it involves secret keys.

My project uses Rails 5 and the Devise gem.

I read in several places that you don't want to put files like secrets.yml onto github for security reasons (which I discovered several commits down the road). However, my secret keys that are used in production are environment variables (although my development and keys are not, they can be seen).

What I am trying to figure out now, is that is it fine that files like secrets.yml (I also heard some things about database.yml as well), have ended up on github, as long as the important bits (like secret keys) are environment variables, which fortunately Rails seems to have thought of by default? Or should I go through the effort of removing those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the sensitive information (by replacing it with environment variables) then you can commit the file. It's not just `secrets.yml`. Any encryption keys, API keys, credentials, should not be committed to Git.

If you've already pushed this information to Git, it can be removed by doing a Rebase, but that doesn't guarantee that every copy is removed. It would be better to change the secret.

This would mean using an environment variable, setting the existing value in the environment, then at a certain point generating a new value for the secret and changing the environment variable.

Changing the secret would invalidate any existing user sessions, so it would be best to inform users ahead of time and do it during time where the fewest users are using the site.

Until you change the secret value, your site is vulnerable.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, my secrets.yml (and I believe the other important files as well), essentially looks like what I listed at the end of this comment. From what I understand from your answer, it seems that I should be safe, and it's fine in general to push information like secrets.yml as long as the production secret_key_base is an environment variable?  This is what my secrets.yml looks like >>> development: secret_key_base: abc123youcanseethiskey test: secret_key_base: 123456ghgyoucanseethiskey production: secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

Comment: That doesn't contain the actual production secret. The development and test keys are not sensitive information. So no need to worry about that file, it is intended to be checked into Git just like that..

Answer (score 0):

"What I am trying to figure out now, is that is it fine that files like secrets.yml (I also heard some things about database.yml as well), have ended up on github,"

Never commit personal/sensitive information to your Github repos..

It doesn't matter what the file name is; if it has sensitive information, do not push it to your remote repo.

Comment: It's already been pushed, what I'm asking is if I should go through the effort of removing it after it's been up there through several commits. It (secrets.yml) essentially looks like this: 

    development: 
      secret_key_base: abc123youcanseethiskey
    test:
      secret_key_base: 123456ghgyoucanseethiskey

    production:
      secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

What I'm trying to make sense of, is if this particular way is safe enough, which your answer didn't make clear to me.

Comment: If you've already committed it I would change my keys asap. You can rebase too but your keys may have already been scraped.